# Form is valid(ng-valid), even though one of it's input elements is invalid(ng-invalid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form as below

```html
<ng-form name="TestForm" novalidate class="TestCls">
 <div class="testValidation">
     <input type="text" name="FirstName" ng-model="FirstName" ng-required="true" />
     <input type="button" value="Click" ng-disabled="TestForm.$invalid"/>
 </div>
</ng-form>
```

Also, I added one more input element using javascript code as below

```js
var content = "<input type='text' name='LastName' ng-model='LastName' ng-required='true'/>";
var temp = $compile(content)($scope);
$("testValidation").append(temp);
$scope.$apply();
```

After adding the above element, the resulting form will be as below

```html
<ng-form name="TestForm" novalidate class="TestCls">
     <div class="testValidation">
         <input type="text" name="FirstName" ng-model="FirstName" ng-required="true" />
       <input type="text" name="LastName" ng-model="LastName" ng-required="true" />
         <input type="button" value="Click" ng-disabled="TestForm.$invalid"/>
     </div>
    </ng-form>
```

Now the problem is "Click" button is enabled after adding the content to "FirstName" filed. There is one more required field ie.LastName which has to be taken some values.

**ng-valid class is getting added to "TestForm" form, even though ng-invalid class is appended to "LastName" input element**.

It seems, the validation for the dynamically added elements is not working in ng-form.

In my requirement, the form should be enabled only after both "FirstName" and "LastName" were added some values in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the element to the DOM tree first then compile and link it:

```
var content = angular.element("<input type='text' name='LastName' ng-model='LastName' ng-required='true'/>");
$("testValidation").append(content);
$compile(content)($scope);
```

Validation directives may require a reference to form (require:^form), which means it should be connected to the DOM first, before compiling and linking.